# Linux: write tail -f output, plus comments, to a separate text file

Tags: logs, pipe, debugging, tail

The command `tail -f` command is great for tracing, and in terminal it's very helpful to be able to, for example, hit enter, and type a comment like

```
-- after xyz change... --
```

For record purposes, I would like to be able to pipe the tail output to terminal, plus my annotations, to a second file.  Is this possible (other than copying and pasting the output manually)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what you need:

```
sh -c 'tail -f file & cat' | tee file2
```

Note, it duplicates your comments for the terminal output when you press enter.

It works also with `{...}` and `(...)` instead of `sh -c`, but then `tail -f` won't stop running when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: The fact that it duplicates my output on the terminal is not a blocker, after all I'm using those lines to separate

Comment: What shell is your `sh -c` ? a shell that kills its background jobs on exit/interrupt seems non-standard

Comment: It is dash ....

Comment: How does your Dash kill the `tail` on ctrl-c ? `dash` on my ubuntu (14 and 19) doesn't do it, which is what I'd expect because that `sh -c` command has no job control enabled, thus background processes are started immune to SIGINT (POSIX defined behavior for shells), and AFAIK `dash` doesn't kill its children automatically on exit either

Answer (score -1):

Use Tee

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | tee test.txt
```

Comment: this doesn't add the comments to the file